# React - Make Child component shrink when parent component shrinks

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I have something very simple.

I have a Banner component that looks as follows

```
const banner = (props: IBannerProps) => {
  // ...
  return (
    <div className={classes.Banner}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

And a Card component

```
const card = (props: ICardProps) => {
    return <div className={classes.Card}>{props.children}</div>;
};
```

I want to use them as follows

```
const home = () => (
    <>
        <Banner backgroundImage="home">
            <Card> Quack </Card>
        </Banner>
    </>
);
```

Now, the idea is that I want the card to shrink in size as the banner shrinks in size.

Right now, my banner css is as follows

```
.Banner {
    background-image: // some image
    height: 60vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-position: center -280px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

And my card is

```
.card {
    border: 2px solid green;
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
}
```

What is happening is that my card height is bigger than my banner height when i shrink the page --> see pic

[image]

Comment: no, it's not about height but about the background image inside the banner ... the -280px is the culprit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you should be able to resolve your problem by making the following changes to your CSS:

```
.Banner {
    background-image: // some image
    height: 60vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-position: center; // remove -280px
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

    // Add this to allow absolute position of child card
    position:relative;
}

.card {
    border: 2px solid green;
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
}

// When a card exists in banner, position it with absolute
// and force the boundary of the card to match the boundary
// of the banner
.Banner .card { 
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```